# Why does the review audit take longer to load than a normal review?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-audits

Is it only me that notices when a review audit is about to load, it could take about at least 2 seconds. An actual review usually only takes 1 second to load.

Is the review test generated each time when it's needed? Is so, why don't cache the review test somewhere in the database?

Comment: @iStimple, Thanks. You're right it doesn't happen all the time, perhaps only for longer body (content).

Comment: Maybe because the post get randomly picked at that time instead of just popping the next real one out.

Comment: don't you know? Audits are kept in Shog's backpack. Every time system wants to audit you, it sends a little elf to Shog to pick it from there. Little elves trade union rules forbid caching, that's why this happens in real time. Consider yourself lucky that little elves fly really fast, otherwise it would take even longer

Comment: @gnat, I have no knowledge about the implementation to generate review audit, but if it's a suggested edit, based on [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work), it uses `Markov chain algorithm to randomly insert various words`, I mean if it takes long time and can't be optimized, why doesn't the system store the generated review audit in the database per user per day (if it's empty), and simply dequeue from it whenever the system needs it, just an example.

Comment: I'm not sure it's a problem - I imagine most (myself included) have never noticed and therefore it wouldn't affect the results of the Audit.

Comment: I also noticed this. If it takes a longer time to load I'm always more suspicious

Comment: @Ian it can be a problem if someone would make a review bot to farm the badges and, for example, make it reject suggested edits when the loading time was longer than a certain threshold. Of course it's probably an unlikely scenario, but possible.

Comment: if seriously, consider that audits can be [invalidated at any moment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/197484/165773 "I for one do this rather regularly"). Straightforward caching could easily make meta flooded with complaints like "closed question was given me as known good audit, WTF". To avoid this, one would have to deal with [cache invalidation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1188587/839601), one of "two hard problems in Computer Science"

Comment: @gnat I shouldn't bring cache solution in the first place. I only expect that the generated audit review can be optimized if possible so it will not easily noticeable by reviewers.

Comment: I wouldn't consider it reliable. I'm using my phone for internet right now and review load times may vary considerably just because of that.

Comment: Maybe because it was `...designed to make sure you were paying attention`. And when it takes longer to load, and you notice it, and congratulations, you were paying attention!